# PHP Syntax error (missing operator) when trying to save a date

Tags: php, sql, database, type-conversion

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());


$sql = "INSERT INTO BidList (BidID,JobNumber,Created,Final) 
            VALUES ('$bidid','$jobnumber',$date,'No')";
```

If I do '$date' instead of $date I get a data type mismatch error because 'Created' is of type 'Date/Time' in my database. What is the proper way to save a date into an Microsoft Access database? I need the field type to be 'Date' in my database, so I cannot simply switch that over to text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have quotes around your date. The reason you're getting type mismatch is because dates need to be in the format `Year-month-day` and time goes as `Hours:minutes:seconds`. So You either need to change your data type to `DATETIME` or store it just as date.

From MYSQL manual

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time
>   parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to
>   '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

Comment: Nope.  He tried that already and got an error: `I get a data type mismatch error because 'Created' is of type 'Date'` (This is from the first answer)

Comment: Thank you, I had to specify Date/Time and then 'General Date' in the database to get the correct data type.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want date, then just use the date part.

Change

```
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
```

to

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
```

And the quote is necessary in sql for a date.

Comment: I would like to have both Date and Time here, the database field type is actually Date/Time. 

And I do not believe the quotes are required as I frequently leave them off to insert integers into my database. Adding a quote here converts things to type text which frequently causes data type mismatch errors.

Comment: @Hoser That's for integer, integer doesn't need quotes.

Comment: Ah sorry I thought you meant quotes were always required

Comment: @Hoser despite the fact that integers are recognized without quotes, it is strongly recommended you use quotes explicitly to protect yourself from injections.